# jquery jump menu strips out everything after "?"

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jump menu that I found. It worked great untill I wanted it to go to a page with a "?" in the url. It strips out everything after the "?". 
So when I try to go to mywordpresspage/?id=1, the jump menu takes me to mywordpresspage/.

I don't know alot about jquery ... I mostly work with php.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.site_quick_jump').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            $('#site_quick_jump_form').attr('action', $(this).val()); // 
            $('#site_quick_jump_form').submit(); // Go!
        }
    });
}); // doc ready

</script>  


<form id="site_quick_jump_form" method="get" action="">
  Browse Survey:&nbsp; 
  <select class="site_quick_jump">
    <option></option>
    <option value="mywordpresspage/?id=1">My WordPress Page 1</option>
    <option value="mywordpresspage/?id=2">My WordPress Page 2</option>
    <option value="mywordpresspage/?id=3">My WordPress Page 3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Couldnt you use something like location.href instead of submitting the form?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this requires a quick explanation of parameters on the web.  When you make a request, yuo can send parameters two ways:

1. GET: the parameters are sent as part of the URL ("example.com/?foo=bar")
2. POST: the parameters are sent "behind the scenes ("example.com", {foo:bar})

When you submit a request (ie. when you `$('#site_quick_jump_form').submit()`) you are submitting anything that comes after the "?" in the URL as a parameter.

*** * EDIT * ***

One possible solution is to switch to POST :)  Since that seemed to work for the OP, I won't describe the other options at length, but you also could have:

- made your PHP code just look at all the parameters and re-assemble them in to a URL
- made your JS code separate out the query string (window.location.search) and send it as a separate field

Comment: Oh you are quick. I had figured out the answer and now I understand why it works! Thank-You!!!

Comment: Well, as much as I want the points, it's only fair to point out that they could also just accept their own answer right?  Either way, I 100% agree that the OP should be accepting answers on questions they ask, and they should try and accept the answer that best answered their question (whether it was their own anser or not).

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer, Don't know why it worked, but it did. I changed  action="get" to action="post".

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing that changes in your options is the querystring, you can simplify this by hard coding the action into the form and changing your options to just specify the querystring value.

```js
$(function () {
    $('.site_quick_jump').change(function () {
        if (this.value) {
            this.form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<form id="site_quick_jump_form" method="get" action="mywordpresspage">
    Browse Survey:
    <select class="site_quick_jump" name="id">
        <option></option>
        <option value="1">My WordPress Page 1</option>
        <option value="2">My WordPress Page 2</option>
        <option value="3">My WordPress Page 3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

---

***Explanation:***

When a form is submitted, the form data is created by taking combining each of the form's elements names with its corresponding value, separated by `=`.  Each of those name value pairs are combined with an `&` to form the final form data.

When a form is submitted with `method="post"`, that data is stuffed into the http request's body.  If a user then tries to refresh the page, they'll get a warning that they are about to re-submit their form.  If a user clicks the back button to return to the page, they'll get a warning that the page has expired.  You don't want your users to get these warnings.

But, when a form is submitted with `method="get"`, the form data is appended to the URL after a `?`.  There are no warnings to deal with.